# How to retrieve the full DOM structure using JQuery where input is only a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to to retrieve the full DOM structure when only a button element(which is obviously part of the DOM) is available?

```
$(this) = <button class="btn" id="addBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal"><span class="add"></span> Add...</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Ummmmm.... what?   $('html')? I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you want to receive the entire DOM of the page that the button is located in?

Comment: I think he means **within** a `button`.. as that code sample indicates a `button` is wrapping html.

Comment: I think `button` resolves to `<input type="button" value="click me!" />` on older browsers that don't support it; as a result, I've never actually put html within it. `$(button).html()` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
   {
      // when a change is made in the DOM, this gets fired
      if($('#idOfYOurElement')!==undefined)
      {
        var oEntireDom = $('html').html(); // if you want the content in html
   });
```

Comment: That is dangerous. These event can cause infinite loops if one decides to edit the DOM tree in that event handler.

Comment: Yes it is :D But everything can be dangerous...we are developers :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html").html();
```

Will give you the full DOM